# R function parameters - Can I mandate that one or the other (but not both) be popoulated?

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing, logical-operators, xor

In R it is possible to set up functions with optional arguments by specifying a default value for an argument. For example, if my arguments are x and y=0 then the function requires an input for x. It will use an input for y if one is given, but it will set y= 0 if no value for y is given.

Sometimes I need at least one of two parameters, but getting both could be dangerous if the input is incorrect.

As an example of what I'm thinking about consider that a dataset might have columns for "shift" (AM, PM, Night - a factor) and time of day. If I get a time of day then I can calculate the shift, and getting a value for that parameter is unnecessary. If I get the shift as an input then I don't need the time of day. I want to know approximately what time of day an event happened, so I need one or the other piece of information. Unfortunately, when I get both inputs it is possible that there is a mismatch - the input time might be 8 AM and the input shift might be a PM shift. That's a problem.

Is there a way to configure this requirement (get the shift or get the time, but don't get both) in the function parameters (in the function definition), or do I have to specify both as optional parameters and do the checking within the function (i.e. at least one or the other but not a mismatch)?

Comment: You can't do this in the function signature. As you've already said, you'll have to specify both as optional parameters and do the checking within the function

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this in the function signature.

Your options are:

1. Always accept both arguments, ignoring one when the other is provided. This is not uncommon, and occasionally you see notes in documentation pages like "if argument `foo` is not `NULL`, this argument is ignored".
2. Manually check for mutual exclusivity, and raise an error or warning if both are provided.

Comment: Option three: If you don't want 0 parameters and you don't want 2 parameters, sounds like you want 1 parameter. Give it a more generic name, document it appropriately, and code your function to tell the difference. Using OP's example, call the argument `worktime`, if it's a `POSIX` object then it's a time of day and you can calculate the shift. If it's a string or factor then parse it as described.